# How to make a global loading indicator using promises in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, promise

I'm building a large backbone marionette app where AJAX requests are initiated in various different places (the router and views). I have a single loading indicator on my app ([nprogress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/)) and I'd like it to be `on` while requests are in progress and `off` when all requests are complete. I'm trying to come up with a global handler for these requests to make sure I don't turn off the loading indicator while a request is still in progress.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var vent = new Wreqr.EventAggregator()
    ,promises = [];

vent.on("fetch", function(promise) {
    var wasEmpty = promises.length === 0;

    promise instanceof Array ? promises.concat(promise) : promises.push(promise);
    console.log("Added promise");

    if(wasEmpty) {
        util.loading(true);
        console.log("Loading on");

        $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
            util.loading(false);
            console.log("Loading off");
        });
    }
});
```

I'm using Marionette's EventAggregator, but I don't think you need to be familiar with it to get what I'm trying to do here. I'm creating a "global" `vent` object on which I can `.trigger()` a `fetch` event and pass my promise as the param. I want this object to turn on the loading indicator if it was off, and only turn it off when all requests have completed.

I don't believe this will work as it's written now because `.apply` is applying the contents of `promises` at the time of execution, not by reference, so when I add another promise to the `promises` array a moment later, it's not going to wait for it. It's hard to test this because AJAX requests are so fast, but I'm almost positive that's what's happening.

Anyone ever deal with this before or have a suggestion to how I can have my `$.when()` apply to a global, updated `promises` array?

Comment: Why not just use the [`ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)?

Comment: Because `ajaxStop` would be called for each request that gets completed. How would I know whether there were other requests still outstanding? I wouldn't want to turn off the indicator if that were the case.

Comment: Hang on, now that I read the docs, it may be perfect after all! "Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none remain, jQuery triggers the ajaxStop event."

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that uses Marionette, but the same concepts are applicable to plain Backbone (you'll just have to render, display, close views yourself):

[BackboneJS - How to add a Progressbar while fetching collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008960/backbonejs-how-to-add-a-progressbar-while-fetching-collection/22009106#22009106)

Regarding the ajaxStart and ajaxStop events, just be aware that they will also be triggered by non-Backbone requests, which might not be what you want...